# R display barPlot labels

Tags: r, shiny, bar-chart

Good day it is possible display label here?

[image: image-label]

It is barPlot.

```
output$bar<-{(renderPlot(barplot(data_percent,names.arg =tableData$Country,col=rainbow(length(tableData$Country)))) )}
```

Comment: Can you add sample data please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example with `highcharter` package:

```
library(shiny)
library(highcharter)
library(ggplot2)

ui <- list(highchartOutput("hcontainer",height = "400px",width = "500px"))

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$hcontainer <- renderHighchart({
    hchart(diamonds$cut, type = "column",dataLabels = list(enabled=TRUE))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]